# Generate first 10 numbers of a sequence

Tags: vbscript, sequence, qtp, series

I have been trying to create this sequence:

```
2,7,17,37,67,...
```

I have to print first 10 numbers of the series.

To do this, I have created the following:

```
option explicit
Dim m,n,i,str,d

m=2
d=10
n=7
For i=0 to 10
n=n+d
d=d+10

str=str&n&vbcrlf

msgbox str
next
```

I am unable to print first two numbers, `2` and `7`, as they are declared before the for loop. Even if I store them in a variable called `str`, they get printed after every execution. Is there a way to add these two and print them only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your initial value of `m` to your string before you start running your sequence. Then, append the value of `n` to your string at the *start* of your loop instead of the end so that you capture `n`'s initial value. For example:

```
m=2: d=10: n=7
str = m & vbCrLf              ' Capture initial value of m

For i = 1 to 9
    str = str & n & vbCrLf    ' Capture initial value of n
    n = n + d
    d = d + 10
Next

MsgBox str
```

Note that you're only looping 9 times now, since you've already captured the first number in your sequence (`m`) prior to your loop.

I also moved `MsgBox` outside your loop so that it only appears once, after the full 10-number sequence has been generated.